# In Java, how does BitSet get range works?

Tags: java

pls help me with below code snippet understanding
/*package whatever //do not write package name here */

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.BitSet;

class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        BitSet bs=new BitSet();
        bs.set(4);
        bs.set(0);
        bs.set(3);
        bs.set(6);
        bs.set(8);
        bs.set(10);
        bs.set(11);
        bs.set(12);
        bs.set(14);
        BitSet bs2 = bs.get(4,13);
        System.out.println(bs+"  "+bs2+" "+bs2.get(2)+" "+bs2.get(4)+" "+bs2.get(5)+" "+bs2.get(12)+" "+
        bs2.get(14)+" "+bs2.get(15));
    }
}
```

In above code, how does bs2 gets created from using the get(4,13) on bs?

Comment: Result:
{0, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14}  {0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8} true true false false false false

Comment: What part of the [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) isn't clear? set method sets the bit at the specified index to true and get method returns an new bit set using the specified range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#get-int-int-) states bs2 is a copy of the specified range of bs starting with bit 4 and ending with bit 12 (end index is exclusive). In other words a new BitSet is created that is initialized with the bits set in that range in the original one.

Comment: That doesnt explains how we get {0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8} from {0, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14}, can you explain this exact point?

Comment: @Aditii why not? ``bs.get(4,13)` maps bit 4 of bs to bit 0 of the result, bit 6 of bs to bit 2 of the result, bit 8 of bs to bit 4 of the result, [..], bit 12 of bs to bit 8 of the result. All bits of the result after bit 8 are false.

Comment: Indeed. The copy starts with bit 0, so bs2.get(0) is the same as bs.get(4), which was true in the original.

Answer (score 0):

t is true, f is false!!!

bs:

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}

tffttftftftttft

100110101011101

bs(4-13)

xxxx1010101110x

cause BitSet bs2 = bs.get(4,13);

so bs2 not need 'x' !!!

so bs2 is :

tftftftttf

1010101110

0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8 is 1